# Why SQL Server Migration Assistant keeps crashing on the 'Migrate Data' step?

Tags: sql-server, ssma

I'm trying to migrate a MySQL database to SQL Server using the **SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL**. Converting the schema and synchronizing with SQL Server works fine.

However, after clicking the Migrate Data button, SSMA crashes after a few seconds (*SSMA has stopped working*). What might be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On some certain conditions, SSMA seems to cause problems when using it on a multi-core machine.

I opened the Task Manager and set SSMA's processor affinity to Core 0 only. This fixed the crash and I was able to migrate the whole database.

Comment: This fix also applies to the SSMA for Access (confirmed on version 18.8, the latest version as of today)

Answer (score 6):

One more thing that helped me in addition to setting affinity to `Core 0` only:

SSMA stopped crashing after I set Parallel Data Migration Thread Count to 1. 
You can find it in `Tools > Project settings > Genaral > Migration (in the left pane) > Parallel Data Migration`. Set `Parallel data migration mode` to `Custom` and then `Thread count` to 1.

My current version is 7.0.0, MySQL ODBC Driver version is 5.3.6.

Comment: Interesting, didn't found this option earlier.